# Passing multiple value tu ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this code in mvc 3 razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"))
{
    <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt"/>          
    <input type="image" src="image.gif" alt="" />
}
```

in controller I have this code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string text)
{
    //TODO something with text and return value...
}
```

now, how to send a new value, for exemple id to Action result??? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    // some other properties that you want to work with in your view ...
}
```

and then pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Text = "foo bar";
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // remove the Text property from the ModelState if you intend
    // to modify it in the POST controller action or HTML helpers will
    // use the old value
    ModelState.Remove("Text");
    model.Text = "some new value";
    return View(model);
}
```

and then the view is strongly typed to this model:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text)
    <input type="image" src="image.gif" alt="" />
}
```

Comment: if I want to send only text I must do so, but if i want to send text and id in MyViewModel I need public int id{get;set;}. it is write?

Comment: Exactly, you simply add another property to your view model and then you manipulate this model.

Comment: sorry for stupid question but samthing is not good in this line:
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text) x.Text not contain a dinamic operation

Comment: Make sure you have `@model MyViewModel` on the top of your veiw as shown in my answer?

Comment: i put there @Model MyViewModel

Comment: `@model`, not `@Model`. It's lowercase `m`.

Comment: all is good, but then i rug project i keep an error on this line:
@model ProjectName.Models.MyViewModel